# Why does Git tell me "No such remote 'origin'" when I try to push to origin?

Tags: git, github, push, git-remote

I am very new to Git; I only recently created a GitHub account.

I've just tried to push my very first repository (a sample project), but I'm getting the following error:

```
No such remote 'origin'
```

I ran the following commands:

```
git init
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/VijayNew/NewExample.git
git push -u origin master
```

However, when I ran git commit -m "first commit", I got the following message:

```
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

So then I tried to set `origin`, using

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/VijayNew/NewExample.git
```

But I got the following error:

```
No such remote 'origin'
```

What did I do wrong, and what should I do?

Comment: between the init and the commit add a "git add ." step. What output does "git remote" (or git remote -v") offer you?

Comment: `git remote -v` Nothing is Display.

Comment: Well it seems the origin as not been properly saved then.

Comment: @aymericbeaumet.. What i have to do?

Comment: `git remote add origin ...` should suffice. Was there any error?

Comment: did you add 'git add' ?????

Comment: Now i am getting this error when i try to push `remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/VijayNew/NewExample.git/' not found`

Comment: Sure.. I just update my status. If it is wrong i am sorry @pqnet..

Comment: hae vijay how did you clear the first error ?

Comment: i think again you need to add remote repository.. Come to chat. i ll help you

Comment: I just copy the project into another folder and try from the Beginning. Now i am struck with `remote: Repository not found.`

Comment: oh ..! ok try delete the remote once and add again

Comment: When you are starting a new repository, the first REMOTE command should be git remote add origin git@abc.com:mygit, if you run git remote set-url origin git@abc.com:mygit you will get error message: No such remote 'origin'.  I run into the same problem, and it took a few minutes before I figure this out. Hope this can help others.

Answer (score 281, accepted):

Two problems:

### 1 - You never told Git to start tracking any file

You write that you ran

```
git init
git commit -m "first commit"
```

and that, at that stage, you got

```
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track).
```

Git is telling you that you never told it to start tracking any files in the first place, and it has nothing to take a snapshot of. Therefore, Git creates no commit. Before attempting to commit, you should tell Git (for instance):

> Hey Git, you see that `README.md` file idly sitting in my working directory, there? Could you put it under version control for me? I'd like it to go in my first commit/snapshot/revision...

For that you need to [*stage*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351450/what-does-adding-to-the-index-really-mean-in-git/25352119#25352119) the files of interest, using

```
git add README.md
```

*before* running

```
git commit -m "some descriptive message"
```

### 2 - You haven't set up the remote repository

You then ran

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/VijayNew/NewExample.git
```

After that, your local repository should be able to communicate with the remote repository that resides at the specified URL (https://github.com/VijayNew/NewExample.git)... provided that remote repo actually exists!
However, it seems that you never created that remote repo on GitHub in the first place: at the time of writing this answer, if I try to visit the correponding URL, I get

[image]

Before attempting to push to that remote repository, you need to make sure that the latter actually exists. So go to GitHub and create the remote repo in question. Then and only then will you be able to successfully push with

```
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: @ Jubobs. 1st prob is my mistake. Now i do like this. `git init
git add --all
git commit -m "first commit"`. Now it is working. 2) Actually i have deleted my account before 20 mins. Now I have created a new account. `https://github.com/VijayMobileApp/WindowsPhoneExample.git`

Comment: And still now i am getting `remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/VijayNew/NewExample.git/' not found`

Comment: @Vijay you deleted your old account but still old account in use

Comment: `$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/VijayMobileApp/WindowsPhoneExamp
le.git
fatal: No such remote 'origin'`

Comment: By visiting the URL, I see that you've now created a repo called `WindowsPhoneExample` on your GitHub account, `VijayMobileApp`. All you need to do now is run `git remote add origin https://github.com/VijayMobileApp/WindowsPhoneExample`. Then you should be able to push with `git push -u origin master`.

Comment: Hi @Jubobs. Now it is working. At first I am also give this same url only. Then why it is not working for me. Now I am using url which is you give. Now it's working. Any way thank you Jubobs..!!

Answer (score 80):

I'm guessing you didn't run this command after the commit failed so just actually run this to create the remote :

```
 git remote add origin https://github.com/VijayNew/NewExample.git
```

And the commit failed because you need to `git add` some files you want to track.

Comment: This command only lets the local repo *know about* the remote one. It doesn't actually create the remote repo on the GitHub servers, which I think is what the OP needs to do here.

Comment: I'm well aware of what the command does. From the question I was guessing the user probably pasted all the commands at once and the commit failed so he never actually added the remote.

Comment: Just to be clear, I wasn't suggesting that you don't know what `git remote add` does `:)` Just that you didn't consider the possibility that the OP had never created the remote repo.

Comment: I had the same issue, and I had already created the remote repo. This answer was the solution.

Comment: This is what I needed, the command line (set-url) was suggestion --add which didn't work at all. thanks

Answer (score 37):

I faced this issue when I was tring to link a locally created repo with a blank repo on github.
Initially I was trying `git remote set-url` but I had to do `git remote add` instead.

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/VijayNew/NewExample.git
```

Comment: That did it for me - a little odd because I received the instruction to use `set-url` command from BitBucket's own instructions on "what to do next"

Answer (score 18):

The following steps work for me:

## Init

First, initialize the repository to work with `Git`, so that any file changes are tracked:

```
git init
```

## Create alias [origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529497/what-is-origin-in-git)

Then, check that the remote repository that you want to associate with the **alias** `origin` exists, if not, create it in `git` first.

```
$ git ls-remote https://github.com/repo-owner/repo-name.git/
```

If it exists, associate it with the *remote **alias** "origin"*:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com:/repo-owner/repo-name.git
```

and check to which URL, the *remote **alias** "origin"* belongs to by using `git remote -v`:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com:/repo-owner/repo-name.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com:/repo-owner/repo-name.git (push)
```

## Verify alias origin

Next, **verify** if your **alias** [origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529497/what-is-origin-in-git) is properly **aliased** as follows:

```
$ cat ./.git/config
:
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com:/repo-owner/repo-name.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
:
```

You **must** see this section `[remote "origin"]`. You can consider to use [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com) available for both Windows and MacOS, which help me to automatically populate the missing section/s in `~./git/config` file OR you can manually add it, not great, but hey it works!

## Pull any contents from remote main branch

```
$ git pull origin main
```

This will pull any contents you have on the repository you just aliased to `origin` to the local repository, including `.gitignore`, creating the branch `main` in the process.

## Check main branch

```
$ git branch
* main
```

This will show you that `main` branch has been created and you are now on it(as indicated by the * ).

## Optional

You might also want to change the `origin` **alias** to make it more intuitive, especially if you are working with multiple `origin`:

```
git remote rename origin my-super-git-repo
```

## Finally

```
git add .
git status //If you want to check what's going to be committed
git commit -m 'First commit' //-m is for message
git push origin main
```

You will see a bunch of lines as follows:

> Enumerating objects: 22, done. 
> Counting objects: 100% (22/22), done.
> Delta compression using up to 8 threads 
> Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done. 
> Writing objects: 100% (21/21), 4.29 KiB | 292.00 KiB/s, done. 
> Total 21 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0 
> remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), done. 
> To https://github.com/repo-owner/repo-name.git 
> 948279c..1f3b0b8  main -> main