# Does GIT support master/slave concept like SVN?

Tags: git

I'm quite new to GIT and still learning concepts so kindly bear with me.

Is it possible to setup master-slave setup in GIT . Say at location A(server A) all the commit activities are happening and it has to be pushed to location B which will act as a master. Sync b/n A to B can happen nightly.

Its like we don't to use our master @ location B to commit , pull etc due to bandwidth restriction .All the version control activities has to be done from location A only. IS it possible, if so how ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748978/personal-vs-central-repositories/25749388#25749388) should be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this easily with a post-receive githook (a script that gets triggered by git on the remote server after a push happens)

http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks