# Will git keep the staged object after unstaging a file

Tags: git

As I understand from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25352119/1562087) answer, each time I stage a file (or part of), git will create an index of the file as blob for including in the next commit.

The question is: will git keep that content after I unstage that file out of the index (as git suggest: `git reset HEAD -- file`). May be in the form of some dangling object as long as I'm not doing a garbage collect.

Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: What `git` command would you be able to use to access that dangling object?

Comment: I'm not going to intentionally access that dangling objects, I'm just thinking of a chance to recover a file if it's lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will have a dangling object.

```
me@myvm:/scratch/index2  (master)$ git hash-object foo
aff2b43e2799984a7b49aaafdeae5c424f7e4121
me@myvm:/scratch/index2  (master)$ git add foo
me@myvm:/scratch/index2  (master)$ git reset foo
me@myvm:/scratch/index2  (master)$ git fsck
notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master)
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
notice: No default references
dangling blob aff2b43e2799984a7b49aaafdeae5c424f7e4121
me@myvm:/scratch/index2  (master)$
```

Comment: Thanks, you've just answer @TimBiegeleisen 's question. BTW, you can recover an accidentally deleted file by a `git fsck` if you've ever index it. Just in case!