# Git - Add File That Already Exists?

Tags: git

Searched for this specific issue, haven't been able to find anything relative. I've cloned a repository, no issue - git 'status' returns on master branch and clean. I then checkout a particular branch, say 'dev'. I then fetch n pull (nothing to do). OK... fine...

```
$> git checkout -b bug_000120
```

No issues, now on branch 'bug_000120' and ready to do some quick changes. After modifying file(s), I quickly check the status...

```
$> git status
# On branch bug_000120
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   core/user_manager.class.php
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I don't get this... no changes to commit?!? Add the file? It already existed prior to the modifications...

With all due respect, anyone? Something cement-headed I'm overlooking? I'm just at a loss... or is this expected?!? I would think the changes would be staged for commit and then push...

Any/all comments are greatly appreciated and welcomed!

Thanx in advance...

Comment: Not to be rude, but consider reading an introductory git tutorial?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351450/what-does-adding-to-the-index-really-mean-in-git

Comment: Thanx, Jobobs...

I experienced 'mental flatulence' when switching branches to get this hotfix worked out...

See my reply below to Roujo...

\m/ ;-) ,,,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would think the changes would be staged for commit

That's what `git add` does, actually. `git add file` means "Add `file` to the commit I'm about to make". If the file didn't exist in the repository, the commit will add it. If it *did* exist, the commit will consist of changing the file instead.

This allows you to only multiple files without having to commit all of them at the same time - you would just `git add` the ones that you want to commit and leave the rest of them alone.

You can take a look at the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add). There's also a [nice tutorial by Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-add).

Comment: That's what I was originally thinking, I merely got confused... I had been working on another branch for so long the status message just had me momentarily taken aback when I had to quickly do this hotfix... (D'oh!)

Thanx for the clarification, Roujo... more coffee for me... *winks*